# Middle mouse button

Tags: mouse

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use the middle mouse button to scroll in eos loki?
Normally by clicking the middle button (the scroll wheel) it will allow me to scroll up and down the page using the mouse however I can't see a way to activate this.

To expand the question as requested..

Type of mouse: I have tried an old genius mouse, a lenovo USB wired laser mouse and finally a logitec wireless. The result is the same. When I push the scroll button down so it clicks as the middle button it has no affect. Normally I would expect I can scroll up and down a page without using the scroll wheel until I click the middle button.

Not sure what more details to add.

Comment: Could you expand your question to include the type of mouse you're using? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called autoscrolling and the application must provide explicit support for it.

Answer taken from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/993672):

> with Firefox version 57 the path is the following: Menu ➜ Preferences ➜ General, then all the way down in the Browsing section check the box Use auto scrolling.
>   You can also just type auto in the search field once you're in the Preferences window.